# Python: Sorting a list of dictionaries by a value from a list of tuples in the dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I'm have trouble with lists and dictionaries. I have a list of dictionaries of skiers. Similar to below:

```
skier_1 = {'id': 123,
           'first_name': 'John',
           'last_name': 'Smith',
           'times': [('race_1', 32.25), ('race_2', 33.5), ('race_3', 44)]}

skier_2 = {'id': 234,
           'first_name': 'Allison',
           'last_name': 'Anderson',
           'times': [('race_1', 29.5), ('race_2', 41), ('race_3', 40.25)]}

skier_3 = {'id': 456,
           'first_name': 'Bob',
           'last_name': 'Johnson',
           'times': [('race_1', 31), ('race_2', 41), ('race_3', 39.75)]}

skiers = [skier_1, skier_2, skier_3]
```

I am supposed to write a function to return a list of the n skier dictionaries with the fastest time on the race passed in. If there is a tie, it should be broken by skier id.

```
def fastest_n_times(skiers, race_name, n):
```

I'm getting confused on how to sort the list by a value from a tuple in a list in the dictionary skier_x. My plan was to sort the list completely then just return the n highest. I can sort by skier id pretty easily.

```
def fastest_n_times(skiers, race_name, n):
   by_id = []
   from operator import itemgetter
   by_id = sorted(skiers, key=itemgetter('id'))
```

However, getting the times out of the dictionary. I have no idea. I've tried:

```
for skier in skiers:
    fastest_skiers = sorted(skiers, key=itemgetter(sort_key)(itemgetter('assignments')(skier)))
```

I know this loop isn't the right way. However, this returns an error `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`. I know tuples are immutable, but I don't know why it is not callable?

```
def fastest_n_times(skiers, race_name, n):
   fastest_skiers = []
   from operator import itemgetter
   fastest_skiers = sorted(skiers, key=itemgetter('how to get a specific value from a list of tuples'))
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

edit:

The expected results should be something like:

```
print(fastest_n_times(skiers, 'race_1', 2))
> [skier_2, skier_3]

print(fastest_n_times(skiers,'race_3', 3))
> [skier_3, skier_2, skier_1]

print(fastest_n_times(skiers, 'race_1', 2))
> [skier_2, skier_1]

print(fastest_n_times(skiers, 'race_2', 3))
> [skier_1, skier_2, skier_3]

print(fastest_n_times(skiers, 'race_1', 1))
> [skier_2]
```

edit 2:
I am now trying to create my own function for a key. I can get the race times correct, but I don't know how to use it as a key. I have:

```
def fastest_n_times(skiers, race_name, n):
    fastest_times = []

    fastest_times = sorted(skiers, key=get_race_key(???, race_name))
    return(fastest_times[:n])

def get_race_key(skier, race_name):
    key_values = []

    key_values = [y for x,y in skier['race_name'] if x == race_name]
    return(key_values[0])
```

I know normally it would be something like:
      fastest_times = sorted(skiers, key=get_race_key)

but I need that race_name passed in for the correct time.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: What constitutes the "fastest time"? Is it the sum of all the times, or simply the fasted time in the any of the tuples in the list?

Comment: You can use a defined function in the key argument, try to write your own function and use it with sorted.

Comment: It should be the fastest time in the race passed in. So `fastest_n_times(skiers, 'race_2', 2)` would have the 2 fastest times for race_2.

Comment: What is 'n' there and what exactly you want when you pass (skiers,'race_3', 3)) ?

Comment: 'n' is supposed to be the number of skiers returned. For example, if there are 100 skiers in the list.

(skiers, 'race_3', 3) would return the skiers with the top 3 times for 'race_3'

Comment: luxcem, I've been trying to write my own function to use with sorted. I guess I'm still not fully comprehending what I need. I can extract the values of race times, but not really sure what the output of my function should be?

Comment: I am not agree with your expected results: For instance, the 2 fastest skiers of "race_1" are Allison and Bob, not Allison an John…

Comment: Agreed, I edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement your *fastest_n_times* function, you need first to collect the time of the selected *race* for each skier, in order to sort by time.

Then, you can extract the *n* fastest skiers.

For instance:

```
def fastest_n_times(skiers, selected_race, n):
    time_skier_list = []
    for skier in skiers:
        for race, time in skier['times']:
            if race == selected_race:
                time_skier_list.append((time, skier))
    time_skier_list.sort()
    n_fastest = time_skier_list[:n]
    return [f[1] for f in n_fastest]
```

Comment: So we are:
1. Looping through the list of skier dictionaries.

2. Looping through the list of times inside the dictionary

3. Appending the time to a new list of tuples if it matches. [(time, skier_1), (time, skier_2)]

4. cutting it off after n entries

5. returning the second element of the tuples in a list.

Does that seem about right?
I guess I didn't think to create a new list of tuples like that!

Comment: @KyleB: What do you mean? Explain.

Answer (score 0):

For comparing the tuple you have to access times key's values :

```
    import collections
    new_dict = collections.OrderedDict()


    skier_1 = {'id':123,
               'first_name':'John',
               'last_name':'Smith',
                'times':[('race_1',32.25),('race_2',33.5),('race_3',44)]}

    skier_2 = {'id':234,
               'first_name':'Allison',
               'last_name':'Anderson',
                'times':[('race_1',29.5),('race_2',41),('race_3',40.25)]}

    skier_3 = {'id':456,
               'first_name':'Bob',
               'last_name':'Johnson',
                'times':[('race_1',31),('race_2',41),('race_3',39.75)]}

    skiers = [skier_1, skier_2, skier_3]
    skiers_names=['skier_1','skier_2','skier_3']

    for i,j in zip(skiers,skiers_names):
        new_dict[j]=i.get('times')




    new=[]

    for i in skiers:
        new.append(i.get('times'))

    race_1=[]
    race_2=[]
    race_3=[]

    for i in new:
        race_1.append(i[0])
        race_2.append(i[1])
        race_3.append(i[2])

    race_1.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])  # sorts in place
    race_2.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])  # sorts in place
    race_3.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])  # sorts in place





    def fastest_n_times(skiers, race_name, n):

        return_list=[]

        for i in race_name[:n]:
            for j,k in new_dict.items():
                if i in k:
                    if j not in return_list:
                        return_list.append(j)

        return return_list
```

output:

```
>> print(fastest_n_times(skiers, race_1, 2))

['skier_2', 'skier_3']

>> print(fastest_n_times(skiers,race_3, 3))

['skier_3', 'skier_2', 'skier_1']

>> print(fastest_n_times(skiers, race_2, 3))

['skier_1', 'skier_2', 'skier_3']

>> print(fastest_n_times(skiers, race_1, 1))

['skier_2']
```